# Ignore files based on filename in Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -threads 4 -preset medium -   
crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "%%~na.mp4"
```

I have this script to automatically compress video files in using the x265 codec. Sometimes the compressed files end up being larger than the source files. In those cases I will affix *_OPTI* at the end of the filename.

> example
>
> Original:
> 1.mp4
>
> Renamed: 1_OPTI.mp4

My question how can batch script filter out the _OPTI files in the folder that has _OPTI in the filename and ignore them when it adds files in the compression queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this in a batch file

```
setlocal enableextensions
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir /b *.mp4 ^| findstr /V OPTI`) do (
echo ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -threads 4 -preset medium -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "%%~na.mp4"
)
```

Comment: In case the file names contain spaces you should include either `delims=` or `tokens=*` in the for options. And I think it' s `OPTI` not `OPT1`

Comment: This almost works, but with files that have spaces in them e.g.,

"Cool Movie 1.mp4"  

the script is only grabbing "cool"

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I have updated the for statement in the example to us  delims=.  This stops tab and space being using as delimiters when the for statement processes the output from the command, so filenames with spaces in them should be processed correctly now.

Comment: Thansk that worked, I had to take out the echo in front of the ffmpeg but it did exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks to you both